# Export app from ios simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have a app run on iPad simulator. I am trying to export it and install it to other simulator in other mac ?

but can't find a way. Anyone can help ?

Comment: How did the app get on the iOS simulator?

Comment: May be can copy app out from simulator folder, Yes, I haven't found a way to copy a app out from simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to export it and install it to other simulator in other mac ?

You can't. That's not how the simulator works. To run the app on another Mac, you need to copy the Xcode project to the other Mac and run that project in Xcode on that other Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the xcode application to the other mac and try to build in the same mac to which you imported the file with the desired simulator.